# click on url links in my webapp downloads the page and sometimes click gets disabled what could be possible reason?

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, cross-browser

```
<div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MainMenu_pnlmenu" class="menu" style="display:inline-block;margin-left:50px; float:right;right:100px;bottom:0px; position:relative; background-color:Transparent;">        
<ul id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MainMenu_Menuid" class="">
    <li rel="2"><a href=http://localhost:2196/MYAPP/User/Default.aspx>Home</a></li>
    <li rel="4"><a href=http://localhost:2196/MYAPP/about .aspx>About us</a></li>
    <li rel="3"><a href=http://localhost:2196/MYAPP/contact.aspx>Contact us</a></li>
</ul>
```

I dont understand what could be possible reason?? suggest me something please.

Comment: Is this actually your code? With spaces and no quotes in href attributes?

Comment: Actually these are being generated dynamically i never checked it in source html as it was working good. thank you so much for pointing out this mistake this explains why page might get downloaded....
i made it like this
href='http://localhost:2196/MYAPP/contact.aspx' lets see if this error occurs again.

Answer (score 1):

You've some errors in your `<a>` elements.

Try:

```
<div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MainMenu_pnlmenu" class="menu" style="display:inline-block;margin-left:50px; float:right;right:100px;bottom:0px; position:relative; background-color:Transparent;">

<ul id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MainMenu_Menuid" class="">
    <li rel="2"><a href="http://localhost:2196/MYAPP/User/Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
    <li rel="4"><a href="http://localhost:2196/MYAPP/about.aspx">About us</a></li>
    <li rel="3"><a href="http://localhost:2196/MYAPP/contact.aspx">Contact us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `space` from the below URL and it will work.

**For Instance,**

**Incorrect:**
`http://localhost:2196/MYAPP/about .aspx`

**Correct:**
`http://localhost:2196/MYAPP/about.aspx`

Hope this helps.

Comment: then why does it works mostly but some time i get this unclickable problem ,and what about downloading why page gets downloaded when clicked url.